# How to save my form as an SVG using Skia4Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, skia, skia4delphi

I've seen people mentioning on forums in the past that it's possible to save your form with all of the components on it as an SVG using Skia.

But how can this be achieved? I tried looking for functions that allow this, but I can't find any.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why asking here and not where you read it?

Comment: @AmigoJack I ask here because Stack Overflow is meant for this (Questions+Answers) and this specific question has not been asked on Stack Overflow yet. Have a read here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/22824066

Comment: Then why not at least linking to "_I've seen people mentioning on forums_" in your Q? Why hiding what you already found from others when you're interested in spreading knowlegde on SO? That's inconsistent - you don't have to choose between wanting help or being a help - **you also** can be both.